# how to sort results from a simple SQL query

Tags: sql, count, rows

My SQL

```
SELECT nce.id, nce.send, count( * ) AS total
FROM `newsletter_email` nce
WHERE 1
GROUP BY nce.id, nce.send
```

Produces the result:

```
id  send    total
4   0       6
4   1       1
5   0       2
6   1       7
7   1       4
8   0       2
8   1       4
9   1       1
```

But I want the result to be:

```
id  send    no_send     total
4   6       1           7
5   0       2           2
6   7       0           7
7   4       0           4
8   4       2           6
9   1       0           1
```

I have tried several ways but it did not give the expected result. Can you help?

Comment: Please define what the 'send' and 'no_send' columns mean. Is 'send' the index of a particular send event? I see only 1s and 0s in that column, so it's not totally clear how the first result maps to the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming Send has value of 1 for send and 0 for no_send, you can simply sum values of send:

```
SELECT nce.id, 
   sum(nce.send) as Send, 
   sum(1 - nce.send) as NO_send, 
   count(nce.send) as Total
FROM `newsletter_email` nce
GROUP BY nce.id
```

However, general pattern would be:

```
SELECT nce.id, 
   sum(case when nce.send = 1 then 1 end) as Send, 
   sum(case when nce.send = 0 then 1 end) as NO_send, 
   count(nce.send) as Total
FROM `newsletter_email` nce
GROUP BY nce.id
```